# store multiple files at their specific fields in database with codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, file, codeigniter, upload

I am creating a form with 20+ fields to submit the details of the employee's. In the form the employee has to fill their details and upload their document. There are five fields for documents namely (photo,idcard,licence,cv,attest) so the name of each uploaded document has to be stored in a particular field . If i upload all the files in sequence then it is working fine but how to insert the name of a file to their designated field if the employee only inserts one or two files. 
Hope i am making sense.

controller

```
 public function register()
    {
    //form validation   

    if($this->form_validation->run() === False){
        $this->load->view('form');
    }
    else{

    //uploading files   
    $number_of_files = sizeof(array_filter($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));
    $files = $_FILES['file'];
    $errors = array();
    for($i=0;$i<$number_of_files;$i++)
    {
        if($_FILES['file']['error'][$i] != 0)
        {
            $error[$i] = array('error' => 'Couldn\'t upload file '.$_FILES['file']['name'][$i]);
            $this->load->view('form',$error);
        }
    }

    //create a new directory for each new user
    $dir = $this->input->post('fname').'_'.$this->input->post('country');
    if( is_dir(FCPATH . 'uploads/'.$dir) === false )
    {
        mkdir(FCPATH . 'uploads/'.$dir);
    }
    $this->load->library('upload');
    $config['upload_path'] = FCPATH . 'uploads/'.$dir;
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|docx';

    for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_files; $i++) {
    $_FILES['file']['name'] = $files['name'][$i];
    $_FILES['file']['type'] = $files['type'][$i];
    $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] = $files['tmp_name'][$i];
    $_FILES['file']['error'] = $files['error'][$i];
    $_FILES['file']['size'] = $files['size'][$i];
    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    // we retrieve the number of files that were uploaded
    if ($this->upload->do_upload('file'))
    {
       $data['uploads'][$i] = $this->upload->data();
    }
    else
    {
      $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
      $this->load->view('form',$error);
    }
    }
    //assign names of uploaded files to insert in database
    if($data){
        foreach($data as $value){
    $photo   = FCPATH . 'uploads/'.$dir.$value[0]['file_name'];
    $idProof = FCPATH . 'uploads/'.$dir.$value[1]['file_name'];
    $cv      = FCPATH . 'uploads/'.$dir.$value[2]['file_name'];
    $license = FCPATH . 'uploads/'.$dir.$value[3]['file_name'];
    $attest  = FCPATH . 'uploads/'.$dir.$value[4]['file_name'];
    }
    }
     $this->form_model->insert_users($photo,$idProof,$cv,$license,$attest);
    redirect('form/registered');    
    }   
    }
```

model

```
public function insert_users($photo,$idProof,$cv,$license,$attest){

$data = array(
//other fields...
'other'     => $this->input->post('other'),
'photo'     => $photo,
'idProof'   => $idProof,
'cv'        => $cv,
'license'   => $license,
'attest'    => $attest
);
return $this->db->insert('employee',$data);
}
```

View

```
   <input type='file' name='file[]' onchange="readURL(this);" />
   <input type='file' name='file[]' onchange="readURL(this);" />
   <input type='file' name='file[]' onchange="readURL(this);" />
   <input type='file' name='file[]' onchange="readURL(this);" />
   <input type='file' name='file[]' onchange="readURL(this);" />
```

Comment: Just give the file input fields the same name as the document column so you know exactly which files are submitted.

Comment: Then do i need to put each fields name in $this->upload->do_upload('file')